# React pushing to array duplicates it instead of adding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Can anybody help me with this issue? I have a state called "filteredPokemon" which fetches a list of pokemon based on some things, then I pass it to this function called PokemonDisplayArea where I proceed to display the list of pokemon. However, when I change offset I expect the behavior to ADD onto the previous state of "Cards" which are the element rendering the HTML, however instead, it grabs the newest filteredpokemon and appends it twice. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is a video
https://clipchamp.com/watch/EcMJbOMjOaL

The code:

```
function PokemonDisplayArea({pokemons}) {

const [filteredPokemon, setFilteredPokemon] = useState([]);
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(20);
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);




useEffect(() => {
  let cardsSkele = [];

  if (filteredPokemon.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < filteredPokemon.length; i++) {
      if (undefined !== filteredPokemon[i].name) {

        cardsSkele.push(<PokemonCard key={filteredPokemon[i].id} name={filteredPokemon[i].name}></PokemonCard>);
        cardsSkele.sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key)
      }
    }
    setCards(prevArray => [...prevArray, ...cardsSkele]);


  }


}, [filteredPokemon])




  // SEARCH POKEMON RESULTS

  // FILTER POKEMON RESULTS




  return (
    <div className="pokemon__display-area">
      <GetFilteredPokemon pokemons={pokemons} amount={20} offset={offset} filteredPokemon={filteredPokemon} setFilteredPokemon={setFilteredPokemon}></GetFilteredPokemon>
      {cards}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am a beginner, thanks!

I tried passing different states into useEffect, and tried console logging the data but the data seems to change fine, and the list just duplicates.

Comment: Instead of creating a new new array of existing cards in useEffect, you will need to first check if the item in the filteredPokemon is part of the existing cards and club the data and consolidate, which will remove the duplication

Comment: Is the purpose of this `useEffect` to set `cards` for just items in `filteredPokemon`? Or is it to set `cards` for previous items and filtered combined?

Comment: @JohnLi It is supposed to grab the changed updated data from filteredPokemon and append the new ones to the previous ones already there.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would just store data in the state rather than components itself as it easy to reason about and transform.

Iterate over the cards and update the data for existing items or add the new item. Something along these lines.

```
function getUpdatedCardsData(prevCards, filteredPokemon) {
  // get list of all the ids for the filtered pokemons
  const filteredPokemonIds = filteredPokemon.map(fp => fp.id);

  // This will combine the data for existing cards that are part of 
  // filteredPokemon and maintain a map of ids that are new and need to be added to cards
  const updatedCards = prevCards.reduce((memo, card) => {
    const cardId = card.id;

    const isNewCard =  !filteredPokemonIds.includes(cardId);

    // add it to the map if new
    if(isNewCard) {
      memo.newCardIds.push(cardId);
    } else {
      // find the card that is in filtered pokemon
      const found = filteredPokemon.find(fp => fp.id === cardId);

      if(found) {
        const updatedCard = {
          ...card,
          ...found
        };

        memo.updatedCards.push(updatedCard);
      }
    }

    return memo;
  }, {
    updatedCards: [],
    newCardIds: []
  });
}

function getNewCards(newCardIds, filteredPokemon) {
 // List of the new cards 
  const newCards = newCardIds.reduce((memo, newCardId) => {
    const found = filteredPokemon.find(fp => fp.id === newCardId);

    if(found) {
      memo.push(found);
    }

    return memo;
  }, []);
}

function PokemonDisplayArea({pokemons}) {

const [filteredPokemon, setFilteredPokemon] = useState([]);
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(20);
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    if(filteredPokemon) {
    setCards(prevCards => {
        const {
        updatedCards,
        newCardIds
      } = getUpdatedCardsData(prevCards, filteredPokemon);
      
      const newCards = getNewCards(newCardIds, filteredPokemon);
      
      // add updated and new and sort them
      const sortedCards = [...updatedCards, ...newCards].sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      
      return sortedCards;
    });
  }
}, [filteredPokemon])




  // SEARCH POKEMON RESULTS

  // FILTER POKEMON RESULTS




  return (
    <div className="pokemon__display-area">
      <GetFilteredPokemon 
         pokemons={pokemons}
         amount={20} 
         offset={offset} 
         filteredPokemon={filteredPokemon} 
         setFilteredPokemon={setFilteredPokemon}
       />
       
      {cards.map((card, i) => {
        const pokemon = card[i];
        
        return (
            <PokemonCard 
               key={pokemon.id} 
               name={pokemon.name}
          />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```